# Run a Bash Script Automatically After 10 Mins When the Codition Fails

Tags: bash

```
if [ $FILE_SIZE -ge 5000000000 and $FILE_SIZE -le 10000000000 ]

then

 cp $s/* $W

else

#Here I need to wait the script for 10 minutes and re-run the if condition again

echo "file $myfile is out of Limit"

fi
```

Comment: write a sleep 10 min in while (condition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `sleep` to wait for 10 minutes, like so:

```
while true ; do
  if [ "$FILE_SIZE" -ge 5000000000 -a "$FILE_SIZE" -le 10000000000 ]  ; then ; break ; fi
  echo "file $myfile is out of Limit"
  sleep 600
done

cp $s/* $W
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [at](http://linux.die.net/man/1/at) to reschedule the script from within the script if the exexution fails. In the else block, put something like:

```
at now + 10 minutes << END
./$0
END
```